# Creating a name for v-model dynamically in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a button to create a new component 'AddressField' in each click. Inside this component I have a input that a I need to store the data inside the input;

Here is the button to activate the logic to create a new component

```
 <div class="col-3 p-1">
      <button 
          type="button" 
          class="btn btn-success col-12" 
          @click="addAddressField">Calculate
      </button>
</div>
```

Reusable component that is created in each click on the button above

```
<ul class="p-0 m-0">
      <address-field
           v-for="(addressfield) in AddressFieldObject"
           :key="addressfield.id"
           :title="addressfield.title"
           v-model="?"
       ></address-field>
</ul>
```

Function to add a component

```
addAddressField() {

    this.AddressFieldObject.push({
          id: 'id' + this.nextAddressFieldID++,
          title: 'title' + this.nextAddressFieldTitle++
         })
        this.newAddressField = ''
         }
```

Is there anyway to create a name for v-model dynamically? For example:

- 1st click / component with v-model name 'nameModel01'
- 2nd click / component with v-model name 'nameModel02'
- 3rd click / component with v-model name 'nameModel03'

In the end, my objective is to store all the input inside a array or a object, just like:

- array = [nameModel01, nameModel02, nameModel03]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use object.

I created an [example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Pay attention on `arr` variable

Comment: Thankssss a lot ;)

I did exactly what you wrote in your example, just a few adapts but it is working properly

Answer (score 0):

Could do like this.

```
<ul class="p-0 m-0">
      <address-field
           v-for="(addressfield, index) in AddressFieldObject"
           :key="addressfield.id"
           :title="addressfield.title"
           v-model="nameModel[index]"
       ></address-field>
</ul>
```

or use addressfield.id instead of index.